# Greasemonkey profanity filter script to work on Youtube comments

Tags: filter, youtube, greasemonkey, profanity

I do not know what I am talking about here I go.

On some pages it filters them and others like Youtube comments don't work. 
What code needs to change in order for it to work in these sites?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        profanity_filter
// @namespace   localhost
// @description Profanity filter
// @include     *
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

function recursiveFindTextNodes(ele) {
  var result = [];
  result = findTextNodes(ele,result);
  return result;
}

function findTextNodes(current,result) {
  for(var i = 0; i < current.childNodes.length; i++) {
    var child = current.childNodes[i];
    if(child.nodeType == 3) {
      result.push(child);
    }
    else {
      result = findTextNodes(child,result);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

var l = recursiveFindTextNodes(document.body);

for(var i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
  var t = l[i].nodeValue;
  t = t.replace(/badword1|badword2|badword3/gi, "****");
  t = t.replace(/badword4/gi, "******");
  t = t.replace(/badword5|badword6|badword7/gi, "*****");
  t = t.replace(/badword8/gi, "******");
  l[i].nodeValue = t;
}
```

* Replaced profanity in code to badword

Comment: Add a demo link to one of the comment pages you're talking about.

Comment: @wOxxOm www.youtube.com/watch?v=AlSDUhNkrQY

Answer (score 0):

Youtube comments are loaded asynchronously, quite a long time after the page has loaded (userscripts by default are executed at `DOMContentLoaded` event), so you need to wrap your code as a callback function of [waitForKeyElements](https://gist.github.com/2625891) with a selector for the comments container or `MutationObserver` or `setInterval`.

```js
replaceNodes(); // process the page
waitForKeyElements('.comment-text-content', replaceNodes);

function replaceNodes() {
    ..............
    ..............
}
```

Using `setInterval` instead of waitForKeyElements:

```js
replaceNodes(); // process the page
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (document.querySelector('.comment-text-content')) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        replaceNodes();
    }
}, 100);

function replaceNodes() {
    ..............
    ..............
}
```

P.S. Don't blindly assign the value to the node, check first if it has changed to avoid layout recalculations:

```js
if (l[i].nodeValue != t) {
    l[i].nodeValue = t;
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to code. I got the code from www.reddit.com/r/awesomenauts/comments/32fim8/a_profanity_filter_extension_for_your_browser/  I guessed how to change it so it writes *** or +++ instead of Zork, Kewlu, Gelati which worked. Don't not know what to do with this code. maybe do a complete code